# Capturing the close using promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, promise, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem inasmuch as I need to execute a method when a ui-bootstrap modal is closed (and has finished animating). I don't know how to write the promise correctly. I have this so far (in TypeScript):

```
public open(attrs, opts) {
    var scope = this.rootScope.$new();
    angular.extend(scope, attrs);

    opts = angular.extend(opts || {}, {
        backdrop: false,
        scope: scope,
        templateUrl: 'splash/content.html',
        windowTemplateUrl: 'splash/index.html'
    });

    this.modalInstance = this.modal.open(opts);

    this.modalInstance.result.then(
        function() {
            console.log("1");
        },
        function() {
            console.log("2");
        },
        function() {
            console.log("3");
        });
}

public close() {
    if (this.modalInstance != null && this.modalInstance != undefined) {
        this.modalInstance.close();
    }
}
```

I have tried attaching a .result to the close method but apparently that doesn't exit: it seems only the open method returns a promise. Can anyone help me out? Only "1" displays in the console and I think this is the open resolve.

Comment: `.result` is the resolve when closing the modal by `.close` or `.dismiss`.  From the documentation - " a promise that is resolved when a modal is closed and rejected when a modal is dismissed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular-ui-bootstrap modal result property returns a promise as you have discovered. The promise is resolved if the modal is closed (confirmed/yes), but the promise is rejected if the modal is dismissed (click outside the modal/cancel).

If you want to call multiple functions after the modal is closed, you can chain them with additional .then() calls.

You can use .catch() to see if the modal was cancelled / dismissed.

```
this.modalInstance.result.then(function() {
  console.log(1);
}).then(function() {
  console.log(2);
}).then(function() {
  console.log(3);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('the modal was dismissed so the promise chain was rejected');
});
```